# Map keeps coming back to my location even after i clicked on a marker

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

lets say i am in position x. My map loads perfectly and it zooms to my location. Now i click on a marker i created in another position, let's say position y. Camera changes and goes to that marker in position y as it should. 
Problem is, it stays there for about 2-3 seconds and then comes back to my location (postion x).
How can i make it stay where i want until i change it back?
Here is the part of my code i think i need to change.
If you need more info, more code, feel free to ask.

```
public void setUpMap() {
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            LatLng l = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(l, 12));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your camera is being update every time the map receives a location update. To avoid this, simply remove the `OnMyLocationChangeListener`.

I understand that you need your map to center on your location only on the map first load. In this case, you can remove the `OnMyLocationChangeListener` from the map the first time it is called using `map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);`:

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng l = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(l, 12));

        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null); // Remove the listener
    }
});
```

Also, take into account that, according to [the documentation of GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener:](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener)

> **This interface is deprecated.**
>
> use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead. FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example example code, or the Location Developer Guide.